# access the src attribute of an image with jquery

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I'm following this example in:

http://bxslider.com/examples/perform-action-transition-callback

But with this example I can get the index number from current image.

I have this code:

```
 $('#preview_images_gallery').bxSlider({
                                        onAfterSlide: function(totalSlides, currentSlide){
                                                                                            var src = $('currentSlide').attr('src');
                                                                                            $('.preview .bx-wrapper .bx-window').append('<p class="check">' + src);
                                                                                         }
                                      });
```

**How can I get the src attribute of current image?**

I write:

```
var src = $(currentSlide).attr('src');
```

**but I get undefined!**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var source = $('img').attr('src');
```

Not tested, and not very efficient, but something like this might work, may need some tweaking.

```
var images = [], source="";
$('#slider1').bxSlider({
    pager: true,
    onBeforeSlide: function(currentSlide, totalSlides){
       $('img', this).each(function() {
           images.push(this);
       });
       source = $(images[currentSlide]).attr('src');
    }
});
alert(source);
```

If macros is correct, it would be:

```
$('#slider1').bxSlider({
        pager: true,
        onBeforeSlide: function(currentSlide, totalSlides, SlideObject){
            source = SlideObject.attr('src');
        }
    });
    alert(source);
```

Comment: I get **undefined** for `var source = $(currentSlide).attr('src');`

Comment: currentSlide is the index of the currentSlide, not a reference to the currentSlide object.  This is in the (unused in the supplied example) 3rd parameter

Comment: Thank you @Macros can you write a example Thank you!

Comment: @adeneo you last response its correct for me :D. Thank you to all!

Comment: Actually my second attempt was just some hack to try and use the index to get the right image, and Macros was the one that made me actually look at the tutorial when mentioning the third parameter. Oh well, I'll give him an upvote to make up for it !

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [API](http://bxslider.com/options)

onBeforeSlide / onAfterSlide both use the same signature below, and you can access the slide object in the 3rd parameter.  You can get the details of the slides contents from this

```
function(currentSlideNumber, totalSlideQty, currentSlideHtmlObject){
  // perform actions here
}
```

Comment: @hyperrjas, if you have only one image per slide then `$(currentSlideHtmlObject).find('img').attr('src')` will do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

to get the attribute of any jquery element, you can use this:

```
$('.selector').attr(attrName);
```

in your case, something like this...

```
$('.slider1 .left').find('img').attr('src');
```

or even more to the point:

```
jQuery('#slider1').find('li.pager:nth-child(currentSlide)').attr('src');
```

you will have to find the most elegant way yourself, but all the answers suggesting using `.attr(attrName)` are correct, you just need to find the right element selector.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend upon your actual html mark-up, but assuming that you are using `li` element for creating the slide then below should do the trick (slider1 is the container ol/ul id)

```
$($('#slider1 li')[currentSlide - 1]).find('img').attr('src');
```

Essentially, we are findind the slide (li) element using the index (currentSlide - 1) and then finding image within slide to get its source attribute. Now, if you have multiple images within a slide then above may not work as expected.

Comment: This response its valid also :D. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be help you

```
document.getElementById("currentSlide_id").src;



var src= $('currentSlide_id').attr('src')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$('#sliderContainer').children().eq(currentSlide).find('img').attr('src')
```

In the linked example, this would be

```
$('#slider1').children().eq(currentSlide).find('img').attr('src')
```